# Firebase deploy function --non-interactive

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I am integrating CI/CD for deploying my firebase functions.

```
firebase use PROJECTID --token FIREBASE_TOKEN
firebase deploy --token FIREBASE_TOKEN --non-interactive
```

Now whenever a function is deleted from index.js, it throws the following exception.

> Error: The following functions are found in your project but do not
>   exist in your local source code:  httpSeeding(us-central1) Aborting
>   because deletion cannot proceed in non-interactive mode. To fix,
>   manually delete the functions by running:     firebase functions:delete
>   httpSeeding --region us-central1

**Is there a way in the non-interactive mode where a deleted functions are removed from the console without running** `firebase functions:delete httpSeeding`??

Comment: Here is the related PR in `firebase-tools` repo: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/949. Merged on Oct 16, 2018.

Comment: Another related PR to `firebase-tools`: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/pull/999

Answer (score 15):

Run deploy with **-f** option, it should delete extra functions in **non-interactive mode**

`firebase deploy --token FIREBASE_TOKEN -f`

From the docs available by running `firebase help deploy`, we see following option:

```
 -f, --force delete Cloud Functions missing from the current working directory without confirmation
```

Comment: I tried "firebase deploy --token my_token -f --non-interactive" but it gives and error " unknown option `-f' "

Comment: Check please, don't need to use --non-interactive

Comment: Also what is your firebase cli version?

Comment: But i have to use "--non-interactive" since its for automated CI/CD.

Comment: firebase tools @ 6.3.0

Comment: What is your firebase tools version in CI/CD environment? Is it 6.3.0 ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187165/discussion-between-jainam-jhaveri-and-imdroid).

Comment: checked "firebase deploy -h" and it is showing -f and --force. But it doesn't work. throwing an error  unknown option `-f'

Answer (score 1):

Just run the same deploy command from your shell.  It will automatically delete functions that are missing from your source.

Also you can delete functions directly from the Cloud console.

Comment: I do not want to delete it manually from the console in an automated process. And, running only "deploy" command works but I am integrating it in CI/CD hence I have to add "--non-interactive" with "deploy" which gives me above error.

Comment: If the CLI just doesn't do what you want, then file a feature request with the details of your use case.  https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/